# Difference between celery get and join

Tags: python, celery

Is there any difference between:

```
 r = group(some_task.s(i) for i in range(10)).apply_async()
 result = r.join()
```

And:

```
 r = group(some_task.s(i) for i in range(10))()
 result = r.get()
```

Celery document uses both examples and I do not see any difference.

Answer (score 12):

**Short answer**

While the `get` and `join` methods for a `group` should return the same results, `get` implements some caching and will probably be more efficient depending on the backend you're using. Unless you really need to use `join` for some edge case, you should use `get`.

**Long answer**

Here is the source for the `get` method of celery's `ResultSet` class which the `GroupResult` class extends.

```
def get(self, timeout=None, propagate=True, interval=0.5,
        callback=None, no_ack=True, on_message=None):
    """See :meth:`join`
    This is here for API compatibility with :class:`AsyncResult`,
    in addition it uses :meth:`join_native` if available for the
    current result backend.
    """
    if self._cache is not None:
        return self._cache
    return (self.join_native if self.supports_native_join else self.join)(
        timeout=timeout, propagate=propagate,
        interval=interval, callback=callback, no_ack=no_ack,
        on_message=on_message,
    )
```

The first thing we see is that the docstring is telling us to look at the `join` method for documentation. Right off the bat, this is an indication that the methods are very similar.

Looking at the body of the `get` method, we can see that it first checks for a cached value and returns that if it's set. If no cached value is found, `get` will call either the `join` or the `join_native` method depending on whether the backend supports native joins. If you find the format of that `return` statement a little confusing, this is essentially the same thing:

```
if self.supports_native_join:
    return self.join_native(timeout=timeout,
                            propagate=propagate,
                            interval=interval,
                            callback=callback,
                            no_ack=no_ack,
                            on_message=on_message)
else:
    return self.join(timeout=timeout,
                     propagate=propagate,
                     interval=interval,
                     callback=callback,
                     no_ack=no_ack,
                     on_message=on_message)
```

The docstring for the `join` method has this to say.

> This can be an expensive operation for result store backends that must
>   resort to polling (e.g., database). You should consider using
>   `join_native` if your backend supports it.

So you *should* be calling `join_native` instead of `join` if your backend supports it. But why bother resorting to conditionally calling one or the other if `get` wraps up this logic for you? Just use `get` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the difference between groups and chords. The question is if you want the result from all your tasks or if you want a task that does something with the results.

**Groups** are used to start several tasks and then join the results in the order that they were invoked.

```
>>> job = group([
...             add.subtask((2, 2)),
...             add.subtask((4, 4)),
...             add.subtask((8, 8)),
...             add.subtask((16, 16)),
...             add.subtask((32, 32)),
... ])
>>> result = job.apply_async()
>>> result.join()
[4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
```

**Chords** are when you want a task that executes after all specified tasks are done.

```
>>> callback = last_task.subtask()
>>> tasks = [task.subtask(...) ... ]
>>> result = chord(tasks)(callback)
>>> result.get()
<output from last_task which have access to the results from the tasks>
```

You can learn more about these here: http://ask.github.io/celery/userguide/tasksets.html

Comment: You can use either get or join on a group, this is not the right answer