# How can i wait until all celery tasks are finished before continuing my code

Tags: python, celery

I have a large csv file that I split into a list of chunks of 100000 rows each, pass each chunk to a function to do complex calculations, and append the result in a global_list.
when the last chunk is finished, i take the global_list and do some statistic on.
How can i ask celery to process all chunks in parallel but to wait until last task/last chunk is finished before executing the function complex_calc on the global_list?

Thank you for your help

```
for chunk in global_chunk_list:
   def func_calc.delay(chunk) #<<<<< use celery tasks

complex_calc(global_list) #<<<<< should only start when processing last chunk is finished 

@celery.task(name='func_calc')     
def func_calc(chunk):
  ...
  #save chunk in a global list
  global_list.append(result)

def complex_calc(global_list):
 ...
```

Comment: Did you try use `join()` ? This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686850/add-n-tasks-to-celery-queue-and-wait-for-the-results) could help :)

Answer (score 12):

The appropriate method is to use [`Group`s](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups) and the `join` method to wait on a set of parallel tasks to finish executing.

```
task_group = group([func_calc.s(chunk) for chunk in global_chunk_list])
result_group = task_group.apply_async()
results = result_group.join()  # wait for all results
```

See also the example from the docs. (One difference is using `join` rather than `get`, which waits for the tasks to finish) See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33259298/5747944).

```
>>> from celery import group
>>> from tasks import add

>>> job = group([
...             add.s(2, 2),
...             add.s(4, 4),
...             add.s(8, 8),
...             add.s(16, 16),
...             add.s(32, 32),
... ])

>>> result = job.apply_async()

>>> result.ready()  # have all subtasks completed?
True
>>> result.successful() # were all subtasks successful?
True
>>> result.get()
[4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
```

To do this effectively, you'll need to have a result backend configured.

Comment: Thank you. I am no expert in celery but what is .s in func_calc? I have no attribute s?

Comment: It creates a signature object that `group` uses later on to call the task. It's added by the `@task` decorator (like `.delay` is).